# secondary monitor display setting

Tags: display

I am using vista laptop, when I plug in the secondary monitor, the resolution setting that windows chooses is always incorrect, so I have to change it every time. Is there anyway to fix it? 
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a perfect fix, but [**UltraMon**](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/tour/display_profiles.asp) Display Profiles make things **much** easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an IBM/Lenovo machine, you can use an included software package called ThinkVantage Presentation Director to setup display profiles as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've always found it best to change settings with the little app that is provided by the display manufacturer.